# How to do type conversion?

Tags: f#

```
[for t in 1 .. N ->t/N]

val it : int list = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1]
```

But, I want a list of float values.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[for t in 1 .. N ->float t/ float N]
```